# Correctly replacing a string with another string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am work a site that was coded in c# and uses a ssl cert "secure.mydomain.com
To switch from http to https it uses the following code

```
       if (useSsl)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SharedSSL"]))
            {
                //shared SSL
                result = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SharedSSL"];
            }
            else
            {
                //SSL
               **result = result.Replace("http:/", "https://");**
            }
```

This will switch from "http://mydoman.com" to "https://mydomain.com", but I need "https://secure.mydomin.com".  If I change the code to  **result = result.Replace("http:/", "https://secure");** it takes me to an error page because it is trying to go to "https://secure".

I have been searching for 3 weeks to find a solution and tried so of them but none worked.  Any suggestions on how to correct this?

Answer (score 3):

You have missed the extra forward slash on your http

```
result.Replace("http://", "https://secure.");
```

This will work for you hopefully

Answer (score 0):

As stated by soniic, you've missed a `/`.

This means your string will look like

```
https://secure/.mydomain.com
```

Thats why you're being redirected to `https://secure` instead of `https://secure.mydomain.com`

Comment: I wish to thank you for you prompt help.  Do not know if it worked another problem developed.  When I click on a link that takes me to a secure page it is giving an error that says "The connection was reset.  The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."  The url in the address bar is correct because it states "https://secure.mydomain.com"  What is the best way to track this down?

Comment: Does visiting that url normally (by typing it in the address bar) result in the same error?